# How to use the values in a column to identify which column to analyse in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I have two pandas dataframes, one with raw data, and the other is an analysis output based on data analysis of the first dataframe. The setup is below:

```
df1
P1T P2T P3T
P   N   P
N   P   U
P   P   U
U   U   N

df2
Indicator  Indicator State   Occurrences
P1T        P
P1T        N
P1T        U
P2T        P
P2T        N
P2T        U
P3T        P
P3T        N
P3T        U
```

In `df1`, each column represents an 'Indicator', and each indicator can have three states: 'P', 'N', or 'U'.

`df2` lists each 'Indicator' and the range of states it can have, each representing a different case. It is supposed to then count the number of occurrences of each case and output that number in the 'Occurrences' column. That is,

```
df2
Indicator   Indicator State   Occurrences
P1T         P                 2
P1T         N                 1
P1T         U                 1
P2T         P                 2
P2T         N                 1
P2T         U                 1
P3T         P                 1
P3T         N                 1
P3T         U                 2
```

Is it possible to use the value in the `df2['Indicators']` column to specify the column in `df1` to perform a count in, and then the value in `df2['Indicator State']` column to provide the 'countif' condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for `MultiIndex Series`:

```
df3 = (df1.melt(var_name='Indicator', value_name='Indicator State')
         .groupby(['Indicator','Indicator State'])
         .size()
         .rename('Occurrences'))
```

Another solution with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df3 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).unstack().rename('Occurrences')
```

---

```
print (df3)
Indicator  Indicator State
P1T        N                  1
           P                  2
           U                  1
P2T        N                  1
           P                  2
           U                  1
P3T        N                  1
           P                  1
           U                  2
Name: Occurrences, dtype: int64
```

Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it to original `DataFrame`:

```
#if necessary remove only NaN column 
df2 = df2.drop('Occurrences', axis=1)
df2 = df2.join(df3, on=['Indicator','Indicator State'])
print (df2)
  Indicator Indicator State  Occurrences
0       P1T               P            2
1       P1T               N            1
2       P1T               U            1
3       P2T               P            2
4       P2T               N            1
5       P2T               U            1
6       P3T               P            1
7       P3T               N            1
8       P3T               U            2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, worked like a charm :)